# Deleted SSH keys, now annoying message "Identity Added" on every Terminal launch

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, terminal

So, while trying to work out passwordless login to some remote systems (which is an entirely different issue :) ), I ended up deleting and regenerating my ssh keys with ssh-keygen on Mountain Lion.

Now, every time I launch a terminal, I get the message "Identity Added:" (followed by the path to my id_rsa key file).

Searched the webs, but to no avail. The message doesn't seem to impede anything, but it makes me feel like something isn't setup correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: This is just me launching (although I guess you could say logging in) a terminal on the Mac host. Literally pops up between the "last login" message and my prompt. Every tab or new terminal window I launch does the same thing.

Comment: Did you put something in one of the shell initialization files (~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or possibly ~/.bashrc) that might be causing this?

Comment: You nailed it Gordon. (blush). At some point ssh-add got added in there, probably in the midst of a blizzard of searching and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gordon Davisson](https://superuser.com/users/7778/gordon-davisson) answered it, not sure the right way to close the question. Basically I had added ssh-add into .bash_profile. For some reason I managed to forget that, and didn't even think about the tie in of the terminal to the bash spawning.

Oops!